# Android database error and for some reason cannot update cell in table?

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to update the database to show that something has been uploaded. At the end of the method where I have uploaded the information I have the following code to change a column value from 0 to 1 where 1 means that something has been uploaded but I am getting an error.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.HAS_UPLOADED, "1");
String where = ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData._ID + "=" + contenturi;
String[] value = {"0"};
ContentResolver cr = this.mContext.getContentResolver();
cr.update(ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.CONTENT_URI, cv, where, value);
```

and the error message I am getting is as follows:

```
  Error upldating hasupladed=1 using UPDATE tablename SET hasuploaded=? WHERE _id=1
```

Does anyone see the error here or know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of what is the value of the variable `contenturi`, but you do not need it there. If I am not wrong  the correct code you need is either:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.HAS_UPLOADED, "1");
String where = ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData._ID + "= ?";
String[] value = {"0"};
ContentResolver cr = this.mContext.getContentResolver();
cr.update(ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.CONTENT_URI, cv, where, value);
```

Or even:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.HAS_UPLOADED, "1");
String where = ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData._ID + "= ?";
String[] value = {String.valueOf(contenturi)};
ContentResolver cr = this.mContext.getContentResolver();
cr.update(ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.CONTENT_URI, cv, where, value);
```

Depending on whether you want the id set dynamically or not.

The main difference between my code and yours is that I use the where arguments as they are meant to be used - in the where caluse you place question marks on the places where their values are to be inserted and then Android `SQLiteDatabase` substitutes their values accordingly.